# Chrome extension: "Unsafe attempt to load URL" when accessing external .svg file

Tags: css, xml, svg, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I put together a Chrome extension that injects a `filter` property and value into the page's CSS (upon selecting the particular filter in a popup). Rather than iterating through each element separately, I just filtered the entire page (`document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];`)

It worked just fine when the filter is something "standard" like `blur(5px)` or `grayscale(100%)`. But when I try to use a `url()` pointing to an external .svg file, the console says:

**Unsafe attempt to load URL http://www.EXAMPLEURL.com/assets/filters.svg from frame with URL http://www.ANOTHEREXAMPLEURL.com. Domains, protocols and ports must match.**

Is there a workaround to something like this? I'm sure it's a security feature/bug from Chrome, but it's pretty irritating. I just want to add a color filter to the page I'm on. Thanks guys!

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646388/xmlns-w3-url-for-svg-spec-now-throwing-error-in-chrome

Comment: No dice. Still getting the same error :(. Thanks anyways pblyt!

Comment: Put the filter file on the same domain as the hosting document or configure a webserver to proxy the target domain so that ithe target files appear to be on the host domain.

Comment: It's a cross-origin security restriction. If you can't get the SVG onto the same domain, then you'll probably have to inject the SVG into the page as well.