# Open DocuSign created envelope in a new browser window from SalesForce application button click

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am attempting to open a DocuSign URLin a new browser window from SalesForce on a custom button click. I have the embedded sogning URL to  the DocuSign envelope and I need to open that URL in a new Browser window. When I tried I get below error. Is this even possible to open the envelope in a new browser?

```
Unsafe attempt to load URL data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='.3333 .3333 .3333 0 0 .3333 .3333 .3333 0 0 .3333 .3333 .3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#grayscale from frame with URL https://cs14.salesforce.com/console. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Comment: Are you able to open other URL's from SalesForce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are violating the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policy from the SalesForce application.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39794021/1219543) for possible solution.

Read more about the SalesForce CORS support [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/extend_code_cors.htm)

Also this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159406/visualforce-asset-violating-cors/159536) has some good information.